# NFSv4 ACLs on gpfs

Tags: linux, nfs, access-control-list

I try to use NFSv4 over gpfs, but I'm get the following errors:

```
# nfs4_getfacl file
Operation to request attribute not supported.
# nfs4_setfacl -e file
Operation to request attribute not supported.
Failed to instantiate ACL.
```

I'm working on Linux RH 6 with kernel 2.6.32. The gpfs export:

`/dev/gpfs1 on /gpfs type gpfs (rw,mtime,dev=gpfs1)`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you still have to use mm-cmds (mmgetacl/mmputacl)for accessing the ACLs. Direct syscalls are not yet supported
depending on how your gpfs filesystem is configured (mmlsfs -k) for {posix | nfs4 | all} you'll get the output from mmgetacl in the according format

Comment: Did you intend to start a new sentence with "depending on ..."? If so, please insert a full stop after "supported".

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 5.1.7, it's now supported to manipulate NFS4 ACLs using nfs4_getfacl/nfs4_setfacl. Ref: [KC](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/storage-scale/5.1.7?topic=summary-changes)

> Support for setting the extended system.nfs4_acl attribute
> Support for setting the extend system.nfs4_acl attribute as another method for manipulating NFSv4 ACLs in IBM Spectrum Scale. This is done to support the Linux® NFSv4 ACL command-line tools. The tools in the nfs4-acl-tools package can be used to get and set NFSv4 ACLs for files and directories directly in IBM Spectrum Scale.

```
# nfs4_getfacl smbshare1
# file: smbshare1
A::EVERYONE@:tncy
A::OWNER@:rwaDxtTnNcCoy
A::GROUP@:tncy
A:fdg:10006:rwadxtTnNcy
```